# Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`T_B.N`' given input columns

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks, spark-notebook

I need a help. The error "***Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`T_B.N`' given input columns: []; line 3 pos 10;***" comes out when run the code. How i fix that? Is there an better way to write the query?

My "colleagues" and me have tried to solve in the ways we know, but it hasn't been done anyway.

*Thanks for the attention*

```
UPDATE T_A
SET dimRg =  (CASE
                    WHEN T_B.N < 10000 THEN "Small"
                    WHEN T_B.N > 29000 THEN "Large"
                    ELSE "Medium"
                   END)
WHERE T_A.Rg = T_B.Rg;
```